# Hibernate session.flush throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8.
Oracle Release 12.1.0.2.0 .

I have two entity name as Child and Parent Entity.
They are basically joined entity.

We are using Hibernate batching property for performance reason but when it try to save record in Child entity it throws StackOverflowError.
**Hibernate Batching property**:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property> 
 <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
```

Child Entity HBM

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class entity-name="ChildEntity_Name" table="ChildEntity_DB" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="ID" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <version name="RevisionId" access="field" column="RevisionId" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="undefined" generated="never"/>
    <property name="ModifiedUser" type="java.lang.String" column="ModifiedUser"/>
    <property name="DealName_db" type="java.lang.String" column="DealName_db"/>
    <property name="TotalPrice_db" type="java.lang.Long" column="TotalPrice_db"/>
    <property name="DealDate_db" type="java.lang.String" column="DealDate_db"/>
    <property name="ModifiedDate" type="java.util.Date" column="ModifiedDate"/>
    <property name="CreatedUser" type="java.lang.String" column="CreatedUser"/>
    <property name="CreatedDate" type="java.util.Date" column="CreatedDate"/>
    <many-to-one name="CE_UK" entity-name="Parent_Entity_Name" property-ref="UK_PD1" unique="false" fetch="join" update="true" insert="true">
        <column name="CustID_db" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <properties name="UK_Child" unique="true" insert="true" update="true">
        <property name="DealId_db" type="java.lang.String" column="DealId_db"/>
    </properties>
    
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Parent Entity HBM:

```
   <hibernate-mapping>
<class entity-name="Parent_Entity_Name" table="Parent_Entity_DB" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="ID" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
       <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <version name="RevisionId" access="field" column="RevisionId" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="undefined" generated="never"/>
    <property name="ModifiedUser" type="java.lang.String" column="ModifiedUser" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <property name="CustName_db" type="java.lang.String" column="CustName_db" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <property name="CustAddress_db" type="java.lang.String" column="CustAddress_db" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <property name="ModifiedDate" type="java.util.Date" column="ModifiedDate" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <property name="CreatedUser" type="java.lang.String" column="CreatedUser" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <property name="CreatedDate" type="java.util.Date" column="CreatedDate" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    <properties name="UK_PD1" unique="true" insert="true" update="true" optimistic-lock="true">
        <property name="CustID_db" type="java.lang.String" column="CustID_db" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    </properties>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class TestBatching {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            System.out.println("Got the hibernate session ...");
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("Opening tx ...");

            Map<String, Object> parentEntityMap = new HashMap();
            

            HashMap uniqueKeyMapping = new java.util.HashMap<>();
            uniqueKeyMapping.put("CustID_db", String.valueOf(1));

            parentEntityMap.put("CustID_db", String.valueOf(1));
            parentEntityMap.put("UK_PD1", uniqueKeyMapping);
            parentEntityMap.put("CustName_db", String.valueOf("John"));
            parentEntityMap.put("CustAddress_db", String.valueOf("Mumbai"));

            parentEntityMap.put("ModifiedDate", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2017-11-15 15:30:14.332"));
            parentEntityMap.put("CreatedDate", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2017-11-15 15:30:14.332"));
            parentEntityMap.put("ModifiedUser", String.valueOf("User1"));
            parentEntityMap.put("CreatedUser", String.valueOf("User1"));

            System.out.println("Saving record in Parent Entity ......");
            session.save("Parent_Entity_Name", parentEntityMap);
            System.out.println("Saved record in Parent Entity ......");
            
            
            Map<String, Object> childEntityMap = new HashMap();
            
            HashMap uniqueKeyMapping1 = new java.util.HashMap<>();
            uniqueKeyMapping1.put("DealId_db", String.valueOf(1));
            childEntityMap.put("UK_Child", uniqueKeyMapping1);

            childEntityMap.put("DealId_db", String.valueOf(1));
            childEntityMap.put("CustID_db", String.valueOf(1));

            childEntityMap.put("DealName_db", String.valueOf("SS"));
            childEntityMap.put("DealDate_db", "2017-11-15 15:30:14.332");
            childEntityMap.put("TotalPrice_db", Long.valueOf(100));
            childEntityMap.put("RevisionId", Long.valueOf("1"));

            HashMap fkMapping = new java.util.HashMap<>();
            fkMapping.put("CustID_db", String.valueOf(1));
            fkMapping.put("ID", Long.valueOf("1"));
            fkMapping.put("UK_PD1", fkMapping);
            fkMapping.put("RevisionId", Long.valueOf("1"));

            childEntityMap.put("CE_UK", fkMapping);

            childEntityMap.put("ModifiedDate", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2017-11-15 15:30:14.332"));
            childEntityMap.put("CreatedDate", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2017-11-15 15:30:14.332"));
            childEntityMap.put("ModifiedUser", String.valueOf("User1"));
            childEntityMap.put("CreatedUser", String.valueOf("User1"));


            System.out.println("Saving record in Child Entity ......");
            session.save("ChildEntity_Name", childEntityMap);
            System.out.println("Saved record in Child Entity ......");
            
            System.out.println("Flushing session ......");
            session.flush();
            System.out.println("Flushed session ......");
            
            System.out.println("Commiting tx ......");
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Commited tx ......");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
                System.out.println(" closing hibernate session ...");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Hibernate Configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
            
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>       
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user1</property>                
                  
           
        <!-- Hibernate caching settings -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        
        <!-- Hibernate-c3p0 settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>   
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>   
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        
        <!-- Hibernate-Batching settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
       
       <!-- HBM Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="Child_entity.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Parent_entity.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Output:

```
Got the hibernate session ...
Opening tx ...
Saving record in Parent Entity ......
Saved record in Parent Entity ......
Saving record in Child Entity ......
Saved record in Child Entity ......
Flushing session ......
closing hibernate session ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.hashCode(Long.java:1402)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.hashCode(Objects.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Node.hashCode(HashMap.java:297)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode(AbstractMap.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.hashCode(Objects.java:116)
```

**Note:** Without hibernate batching property it is working fine.

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Well, surely `fkMapping.put("UK_PD1", fkMapping);` is the problematic line

Comment: @crizzis if i remove this how i can store the value of CustID_db in Child table?